# SQL command executes twice using Invoke-SQLCMD

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I'm fighting with an issue which absolutely blows my mind.

I'm writing the restore database script which executes from powershell during deployment.

### Here is my powershell script:

```
Param($RestoreDatabase, $RestoreDatabaseBackupPath, $RestoreDatabaseServer, $RestoreDatabaseUser)

Import-Module "SQLPS"                                   

$sqlcmd="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\sqlcmd.exe"
$variables = ("db=$RestoreDatabase","BackupPath=$RestoreDatabaseBackupPath","user=${RestoreDatabaseUser}")
$inputFile = Join-Path (Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path -Parent) restore.sql

Write-Output "Executing SQLCMD: inputFile=$inputFile, Variables=$variables, ServerInstance=$RestoreDatabaseServer"

Invoke-SQLCmd -InputFile $inputFile -Variable $variables -ServerInstance $RestoreDatabaseServer -AbortOnError -Verbose -QueryTimeout 65535
```

### Restore.sql (this is not original file, but issue still reproducing)

```
 print 'The first message is not repeating';

 use master
 GO

 print 'Setting the single user mode'
 alter database $(db) set single_user with rollback immediate
 GO
```

Everything looks simple, but output of the powershell script is:

```
 WARNING: The names of some imported commands from the module 'SQLPS' include unapproved verbs that might make them less discoverable. To find the commands with unapproved verbs, run the Import-Module command again with the Verbose 
 parameter. For a list of approved verbs, type Get-Verb.
 Executing SQLCMD: inputFile= C:\Path\To\Powershell\restore.sql, Variables=db=MY_DB_STAGING BackupPath=\\Storage\Backups\BACKUP.bak user=SERVERNAME\Checkee, ServerInstance=SERVERNAME\SQLEXPRESS
 VERBOSE: The first message is not repeating
 VERBOSE: Changed database context to 'master'.
 VERBOSE: Setting the single user mode
 VERBOSE: Setting the single user mode
 Invoke-SQLCmd : The pipeline has been stopped.
 At  C:\Path\To\Powershell\Script.ps1:11 char:1
 + Invoke-SQLCmd -InputFile $inputFile -Variable $variables -ServerInstance $Restor ...
 + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], PipelineStoppedException
       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlExectionError,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand

   Invoke-SQLCmd : ALTER DATABASE failed because a lock could not be placed on database 'MY_DATABASE_STAGING'. Try again later.
   ALTER DATABASE statement failed.
   At C:\Path\To\Powershell\Script.ps1 :11 char:1
   + Invoke-SQLCmd -InputFile $inputFile -Variable $variables -ServerInstance $Restor ...
   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], SqlPowerShellSqlExecutionException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlError,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand
```

As you can mention there are 2 similar lines in output

```
VERBOSE: Setting the single user mode
```

I think the command is calling twice somehow, and this is a reason why lock could not be placed

### How I execute the script:

```
  powershell -file Script.ps1 -RestoreDatabase MY_DB_STAGING -RestoreDatabaseBackupPath \\Storage\Backups\BACKUP.bak -RestoreDatabaseServer SERVERNAME\SQLEXPRESS -RestoreDatabaseUser "SERVERNAME\Checkee"
```

P.S. Everything works like a charm from ssms

Comment: No output from the `Write-Output`?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson my bad, copy-paste issue, fixed

Comment: @MadRabbit Please answer your own question and mark that as the answer so this doesn't show up in the list of unanswered questions. Thanks.

Comment: @KeithHill I mislead you, sorry for that. My comment above was about fixing the console output in post. Issue is still actual and I don't have an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mystery of duplicated lines lead me to wrong direction. This is just user rights issue. Script works smoothly under different account.